# How to approve a new version in App store connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

How can i approve a new version in App store connect? 
I mean, i already have a first version of the mobile app available on apple store, 
but now i want to publish a new version.

what i already did was upload it through Xcode -> archive and then in appstoreconnect.apple.com going to TestFlight tag to see there the compilations and it says there are "Missing export compliance" i clicked and said "yes" and "yes" again.

Even doing that the the new version it's still not publish but it says its ready to send, what more do i have to do? I can't find the place to do that.

Comment: it is worth to read through: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/ it contains every step in deep details how to publish an app or its new versions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your build is uploaded on the test flight but not in the app store. For publishing to app store, follow along

You have to make a new version of the app in appstoreconnect[image: make new version]

just click on the plus button and click on iOS

Enter new version number. you will now prepare this version for publishing

- Select the latest build in the build section.
- Add what's new content in the what's new section
- Save and submit for review

Comment: The problem currently is how to get the new build uploaded from Xcode 13. Following the steps in the Distribute App option leads to an error 'The app name you entered is already being used for another app in your account'.