# iOS App Available in TestFlight but Not App Store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have the same problem that was addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243792/how-to-approve-a-new-version-in-app-store-connect), but the answer appears to be outdated.  I am able to view the latest version of my iOS app in TestFlight, but I cannot see it in the App Store section of App Store Connect. In regards to the referenced solution above, navigating to the 'App Information' section of site does not display any opportunity to create a new version for submission to the App Store. Can anyone provide updated instructions?